# Error creating a job with WAS builder plugin in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, websphere, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins running on windows with java version 1.7.0_40 which has WAS Builder Plugin 1.6.1 and Deploy Websphere plugin 1.0 installed. When I try to create a job with deployment configuration for Websphere application server, I get below error on saving new job -

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /job/ibmJob1/configSubmit. Reason:

    Server Error
Caused by:

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/websphere/management/Session
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:608)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:651)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:225)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:566)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:651)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:81)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:73)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/websphere/management/Session
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.websphere.WebSphereAdapter.(WebSphereAdapter.java:62)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.websphere.WAS61Adapter.(WAS61Adapter.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.invokeConstructor(RequestImpl.java:441)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:387)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:604)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:394)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:381)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:549)
    at hudson.util.DescribableList.rebuild(DescribableList.java:144)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.submit(MavenModuleSet.java:825)
    at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1480)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:935)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:274)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:141)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:80)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:566)
    ... 42 more
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/websphere/management/Session
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.websphere.WebSphereAdapter.(WebSphereAdapter.java:62)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.websphere.WAS61Adapter.(WAS61Adapter.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.invokeConstructor(RequestImpl.java:441)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:387)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:604)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:394)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:381)
    at hudson.model.Descriptor.newInstance(Descriptor.java:549)
    at hudson.util.DescribableList.rebuild(DescribableList.java:144)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet.submit(MavenModuleSet.java:825)
    at hudson.model.Job.doConfigSubmit(Job.java:1480)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.doConfigSubmit(AbstractProject.java:935)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:274)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:141)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:80)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:566)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:651)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:225)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:45)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:566)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:651)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:482)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:162)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:89)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:81)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:73)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am new to both jenkins and websphere. Am I making any silly mistake here?

Comment: It seems the problem was with jenkins plugin. I've installed Deploy Websphere plugin manually from [Download jenkins plugins](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/). The mentioned error is gone but now I see AdminClientFactory NoClassFoundError. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello akash, did you find the fix for this error? I'm also encountering this issue.

Comment: @exception it is probably because of WAS builder plugin version and java version. I am not cent per cent sure though.

Comment: Hello akash, tried to reinstall the WAS builder plugin and it worked. Thank you.